# Problemas despues de publicar una aplicacion en visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Estoy realizando un codigo que captura el serial del equipo, al momento del publicarlo en unas estaciones funciona en otras no. Me brinda la siguiente leyenda:
ORÍGENES
Dirección URL de la implementación          : file:///E:/Serial1904/Revisar%20Serial%20PC.application
Dirección URL de la aplicación          : file:///E:/Serial1904/Application%20Files/Revisar%20Serial%20PC_1_0_0_2/Revisar%20Serial%20PC.exe.manifest

IDENTIDADES
Identidad de la implementación      : RevisarPC.application, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=721d98d96dea15a1, processorArchitecture=msil

RESUMEN DE LA APLICACIÓN
* Aplicación instalable.

RESUMEN DEL ERROR
Abajo se muestra un resumen de los errores; los detalles de estos errores se incluyen en el registro.
* La activación de E:\Serial1904\RevisarPC.application dio como resultado una excepción. Se detectaron los siguientes mensajes de error:
+ La conversión especificada no es válida.

RESUMEN DE ERRORES DE TRANSACCIÓN DEL ALMACÉN DE COMPONENTES
No se detectó ningún error de transacción.

ADVERTENCIAS
No se generó ninguna advertencia durante esta operación.

ESTADO DE PROGRESO DE LA OPERACIÓN
* [19/4/2023 15:47:55] : Se ha iniciado la activación de E:\Serial1904\Revisar Serial PC.application.
* [19/4/2023 15:47:56] : El procesamiento del manifiesto de la implementación finalizó correctamente.
* [19/4/2023 15:47:56] : Se ha iniciado la instalación de la aplicación.

DETALLES DEL ERROR
Se detectaron los siguientes errores durante esta operación.
* [19/4/2023 15:47:56] System.InvalidCastException
- La conversión especificada no es válida.
- Origen: System.Deployment
- Seguimiento de la pila:
en System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)
en System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

Comment: ahi hay un invalid cast.. ni idea que puede ser, pero revisa donde haces una transformacion de datos